# Large viewmodel crashes while using Knockout 3.3js with Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am new to asp.net MVC & Knockout.
I have a requirement of displaying Patient details in a grid and at the same time adding a patient.

The patient display displays around 10 records in a knockout table format and it is in the lower half of the page.
The patient insert/update is a form which constitutes the upper half of the page.

When I used to save/edit a patient using knockout the page error shows web server returned error.
When I losd only 3 records in the table the save/edit works fine.

the code follows,
The Client ViewModel

```
  self.save = function () {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.PatientDisplay(), function (pt) {
        pt.DateOfBirth(moment(pt.DateOfBirth()));
        pt.RegdDate(moment(pt.RegdDate()));
    });
    self.PatientModel.RegdDate(moment(self.PatientModel.RegdDate()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    //self.PatientModel.DateOfBirth(moment(self.PatientModel.RegdDate()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Patient/Save/",
        method: "POST",
        data: ko.toJSON(self.PatientModel),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {

            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
            self.resetForm();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 400) {
                $('#MessageToClient').text(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
            else {
                $('#MessageToClient').text('The Web Server had an Error');
            }

        }
    })
}
```

The Server ViewModel

```
        public PatientViewModel PatientModel { get; set; }
    public string MessageToClient { get; set; }
    public List<PatientViewModel> PatientDisplay { get; set; }
    public AddressViewModel AddressModel { get; set; }
    public FeeStructureViewModel FeesModel { get; set; }
    public EmployeeViewModel EmployeeModel { get; set; }
    public List<PatientTypeViewModel> PatientType { get; set; }
    public List<BloodGroup> BloodGroupModel { get; set; }
    public List<Gender> GenderModel { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeViewModel> DocList { get; set; }
    public List<int> DeletePatients { get; set; }

    public PatientEditViewModel()
    {

        PatientModel = new PatientViewModel();
        AddressModel = new AddressViewModel();
        FeesModel = new FeeStructureViewModel();
        EmployeeModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
        PatientType = new List<PatientTypeViewModel>();
        GenderModel = new PatientExtras().GetAllGenders();
        BloodGroupModel = new PatientExtras().GetBloodGroups();
        DocList = new List<EmployeeViewModel>();
        PatientDisplay = new List<PatientViewModel>();
        DeletePatients = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

The Patient ViewModel

```
public PatientViewModel()
    {
        FeeStructure = new List<FeeStructureViewModel>();
        Address = new List<AddressViewModel>();
        Employee = new EmployeeViewModel();
        FeesModel = new FeeStructureViewModel();
        AddressModel = new AddressViewModel();
        MaritalStatus = "Married";
        this.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;

        this.RegdDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public FeeStructureViewModel FeesModel { get; set; }
    public AddressViewModel AddressModel { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public int PatientTypeId { get; set; }
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public EmployeeViewModel Employee { get; set; }
    public List<FeeStructureViewModel> FeeStructure { get; set; }
    public List<AddressViewModel> Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Server: Please Enter a valid First Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Server: Please enter no more than 50 Characters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegdDate { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
```

The Controller

Index Method

```
var employees = hmsDbContext.Employees.ToList();
        var patientTypes = hmsDbContext.PatientTypes.ToList();
        var patients = hmsDbContext.Patients.ToList();
        var departments = hmsDbContext.Departments.ToList();

        employees.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var dept = departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentId == x.DepartmentId).Single();
            var emp = Converter.ConvertToEmployeeVM(x);
            emp.Department = Converter.ConvertToDepartmentVM(dept);
            patientEditViewModel.DocList.Add(emp);
        });

        patientTypes.ForEach(pt =>
        {
            patientEditViewModel.PatientType.Add(Converter.ConvertToPatientTypeVM(pt));
        });

        var patientDisplay = hmsDbContext.Patients.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.RegdDate).Take(3).ToList();

        patientDisplay.ForEach(p =>
        {
            var _patients = Converter.ConvertToPatientVM(p);
            _patients.Employee = Converter.ConvertToEmployeeVM(employees.Where(x => x.EmpId == p.EmpId).Single());

            patientEditViewModel.PatientDisplay.Add(_patients);
        });
```

Save Method

```
  public JsonResult Save(PatientEditViewModel patientEditViewModel)
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ModelStateExceptions(ModelState);
        }

        var patients = new Patient();
        patients = Converter.ConvertToPatient(patientEditViewModel.PatientModel);

        var message = string.Empty;
        //string.Format("{0}'s Record has been Registered Successfully!", patientEditViewModel.PatientModel.FirstName + " " + patientEditViewModel.PatientModel.LastName);

        hmsDbContext.Patients.Attach(patients);
        hmsDbContext.ApplyStateChanges();
```

Please let me know how can I still display 10 records and save one record in a single page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are getting form the server? It might be unrelated to knockout but on how you are saving the records

Comment: I am having a wrapper view model which is holding both data to display and a functionality to edit also. So my wrapped view model is large. The error is web server returned an error.

Comment: You need to investigate the error. put a break point on the server and see what the exception is

Comment: Please refer to the edited question @Luis

Comment: You still havent told us what the error is, can you please replace "The Web Server had an Error" with errorThrown?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The JSON request was too large to be deserialized.

Comment: Looks like you are sending too much data to the server, can you just try to send the record you want to save and not the entire collection? Can you pelase show us you complete Client ViewModel and not just the save method?